# how to achieve 200k rows/s insert performance?

Tags: database, memory, insert

Recently I work on a data collection program. I need to achieve 200k row/s peak insert speed on a 2 CPU(6core) machine.

I am wondering to use memory db, any body can give suggestion?

Comment: And which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres? DB2?

Comment: Consider using [Redis](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks).

Comment: I have test a few RDBMS， all failed. I currently try to use mysql to load in a file, it brings a long delay. So I need a hign performance memory db to do cache. Redis is a KV db, it does not support sql.

Answer (score 0):

We have tested memory enginee under mariadb. It has very high performance. Maybe this is the right answer.

Compare to Oracle timeten, it is opensource.

By the way, this is a HPC application.